# How to properly vim-escape a variable/register

Tags: vim, escape-characters

For example, I want to highlight occurrences of the current yank register, i.e.,

```
:let @/=@"
```

It works, unless `@"` has 'funny' stuff in it like backslash.

I can do

```
:let @/=escape(@", '\\')
```

but I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do, and if it will escape *all* possible problematic characters. Maybe there are others.

Update: ok, I really need to escape more stuff. all the regent special characters at least it seems. so is there a regexp escaping function or variable listing all regexp special chars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is such a list. Here is the escape function I have used for quite a while as part of a macro to search for the currently-selected string:

```
escape(@", '\\/.*$^~[]')
```

**Edit:**

Original answer had extra arguments due to my copying too much from my ~/.vimrc. Here is the mapping in which I used that escape in case having that context may help. Highlighting some text and typing `*` searches for the next occurrence of that text. (Mapping originally written by Jürgen Krämer.)

```
vnoremap <silent> * :<C-U>
          \let old_reg=getreg('"')<bar>
          \let old_regmode=getregtype('"')<cr>
          \gvy/<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
          \escape(@", '\\/.*$^~[]'), '\n', '\\n', 'g')<cr><cr>
          \:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regmode)<cr>
```

Comment: hmm. looks like you have unmatched )

Comment: Within single quotes, you can get away with just one backslash. `escape(@", '\/.*$^~[]')`